# App restarts instead of resuming when relaunching from app icon after home button is pressed in signed apk

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, onresume, onpause

I have an activity in which a form is to be filled by the user.In this activity I am saving data in `onPause` method and show it back when activity resumes.This works perfectly when i test it in debug mode but when i run **signed apk** after pressing home button and **relaunching the app by clicking app icon the launcher activity is shown**.

I have tried following in Manifest inside `formActivity` as stated in the following SO questions

1. `android:launchMode="singleTask"`
2. `android:finishOnTaskLaunch="false"`

[Ques 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405827/android-app-calls-main-launcher-again-instead-of-onresume)
[Ques 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449541/android-application-restarts-when-opened-by-clicking-the-application-icon)

but nothing changed.

It seems like `onResume` never gets called when app icon is pressed after home button.

My `onPause` and `onResume` methods :

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        saveFormData(); //function where i save form data 
    }



@Override
    protected void onResume() {

        if (!isActivityCalledFirsTime) {

            showSavedFormData(); // function where i show saved data

        }
        isActivityCalledFirsTime = false;
        super.onResume();
    }
```

**Problem :**

1) Why `onResume` is not called on relaunching the app by clicking app icon ?

2) Is there any other method other than `onResume` which i can use for signed apk ?

**Note :
Application behaves normally when launched from recent apps after pressing home button**

Comment: So for signed package it doesn't work, have you checked your proguard configuration to be correct?

Comment: Yes I've checked it and it is correct

Comment: Does onCreate get called here instead of onResume?

Comment: No actually nothing gets called from that activity as the previous activity is shown on relaunching.

Comment: please provide working code

Comment: Hi Manishika ,i am also facing same issue, how did you solved it..